# why update-alternatives --config java shows nothing?

Tags: java, linux, jdk, fedora

I install oracle java JDK.rmp.bin on fedora. And installing by ". /jdk.rmp.bin", JDK is installed under /usr/java/jdk folder.

I could compile java files using command "javac" and "java". I could also check the version by "java -version".

But when I type "update-alternatives --config java" nothing appears. Why no java version shows in the terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives are updated from %post and %pre scripts in RPM packages. I think BIN packages do not have this functionality.