# Why does Oracle java not appear in the alternatives command on redhat 6.5?

Tags: command-line, installation, java, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have redhat 6.5 x64 and java preinstalled on it. The command `java - version` shows:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

The command `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java` shows:

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

I need to install Oracle java 7.0_21. So I run a command `yum install jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm` and get at the end:

```
Installed:
  jdk.x86_64 2000:1.7.0_21-fcs

Complete!
```

So then I run again `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java` shows: and it shows the same as before Oracle java installation.

Why just installed java from Orcale is not in the list?

**P.S.**

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/599836/334679) tells that `--config` does not work with `bin` packages but I run `yum install jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm` so it is not the same case. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

The rpm itself has to be created to use alternatives and the rpm from Oracle doesn't use alternatives.  See the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514472/i-had-open-jdk-1-7-on-centos-i-installed-oracles-java-rpm-oracle-java-doesnt) for a discussion on how to set up alternatives for Oracle's rpm.